# Align two divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't align two divs horizontally at the same level in bootstrap. In fact, They are not a the same level horizontally, but either one below the other one (even if there is one left and another right) . In fact I want to align horizontally 
     
and 
     
That's why I used
     
followed by 
    .

here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <br><br><br><br>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
       <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  [...]
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
  [...]
</div>
```

The problem is that your grid has *3 + 9 + 3 (offset) = 15* columns on small screen (**col-sm-X**), and *2 + 10 + 2 (offset) = 14* columns on medium screen (**col-md-X**).

The bootstrap grid has only **12** columns by default.

Removing the offsets should make it work

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  [...]
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
  [...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear as to which elements you are trying to align left or right, however, the shortcut method in bootstrap to do this are the classes "pull-left" or "pull-right". From a CSS perspective, they are adding float: left and float: right to the elements.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar pull-left">
        <br><br><br><br>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main pull-right">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
       <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to specify which divs : in fact i want to align horizontally  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar"> and  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main"> => question updated !!

Answer (score 0):

try the following class:

```
<div class="span6"></div>
<div class="span6"></div>
```

This would give the div a 50% width and align them correctly :)